# Using Html.TextBox with custom property in mvc5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-4

if we have the below code,

```
<input id="Name" name="Name" type="text" data-bind="value: Name" class="title width-7" />
```

we can translate it using `@Html.TextBoxFor` to:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name, new { data_bind="value: Name", @class = "title width-7" })
```

now I have this line that i can't translate the 'placeholder' attribute with `@Html.TextBoxFor`, how can I do that??

```
 <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail3" placeholder="Enter email">
```

thanks...

Comment: It should work... Can you show the helper method you tried?

Comment: I solved it by this code : `@Html.TextBoxFor(model=>model.name, new{@placeholder="",@class=""})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah to make it clear to anyone :

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name, new { data_bind="value: Name", @class = "title width-7" , @placeholder ="Placeholder Here"})
```

Thanks. Hope it helps.